# Record Sharing Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing, apex-managed-sharing, record

Below trigger is giving error while creating sharing records, can some suggests where is the issue. Sharing setting is set to private for external user on this object.

Error:

> AccessLevel (trivial share level Edit, for organization with default level Edit

```
trigger grnk_PunchListShare_Trigger on grnk_PunchList__c (after insert, after update) {

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){

        List<grnk_PunchList__Share> punchListShares = new List<grnk_PunchList__Share>();
        List<grnk_PunchList__Share> punchListSharesUpdate = new List<grnk_PunchList__Share>();

        List<grnk_PunchList__Share> punchInsertedRcrd = new List<grnk_PunchList__Share>([Select id,ParentId,UserOrGroupId,AccessLevel,RowCause from grnk_PunchList__Share]);
        Map<Id,grnk_PunchList__Share> MapParIdShareObj = new Map<Id,grnk_PunchList__Share>();
        for(grnk_PunchList__Share punchShare : punchInsertedRcrd){
            MapParIdShareObj.put(punchShare.ParentId,punchShare);
        }
        User u = [Select ContactId, Contact.AccountId From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        if(u.ContactId == null) return;
        Id AccountId = u.Contact.AccountId;
        system.debug('User Account Id::'+AccountId);

        Set<Id> allInsertedPLIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
        Set<Id> setAccountIdOnPunchList = New set<Id>();
        List<grnk_PunchList__c> lstNewPunchList = trigger.new;
        for(grnk_PunchList__c plRecInst : trigger.new){
            setAccountIdOnPunchList.Add(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c);
        }

        Map<id,List<Contact>> MapIdAccLstConts = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
        for(account acc : [Select id,Name,(select Id,Name,OwnerId from contacts) From Account where id=:setAccountIdOnPunchList]){
            MapIdAccLstConts.put(acc.id,acc.contacts);
        }


        for(grnk_PunchList__c plRecInst : trigger.new){


            if(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c != null && MapIdAccLstConts.containsKey(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c) && AccountId == plRecInst.grnk_Account__c){
                if(MapIdAccLstConts.get(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c).size()>0 && MapIdAccLstConts.get(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c) != null){

                    for(Contact con : MapIdAccLstConts.get(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c)){

                        if(MapParIdShareObj.containsKey(plRecInst.id)){
                            grnk_PunchList__Share updateShare = MapParIdShareObj.get(plRecInst.id);
                            updateShare.UserOrGroupId = con.OwnerId;
                            updateShare.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
                            updateShare.RowCause = Schema.grnk_PunchList__Share.RowCause.grnk_Access_PunchList_By_Customer__c;
                            punchListSharesUpdate.add(updateShare);
                        }else{
                            grnk_PunchList__Share pucnhListShareRec = new grnk_PunchList__Share();
                            pucnhListShareRec.ParentId = plRecInst.Id; // record to be shared Id
                            pucnhListShareRec.UserOrGroupId = con.OwnerId; // User Id
                            pucnhListShareRec.AccessLevel = 'Edit';
                            pucnhListShareRec.RowCause = Schema.grnk_PunchList__Share.RowCause.grnk_Access_PunchList_By_Customer__c;
                            punchListShares.add(pucnhListShareRec);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(punchListShares.size()>0 && punchListShares != null){
            Database.SaveResult[] punchListInsertResult = Database.insert(punchListShares,false);
            // Iterate through each returned result
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : punchListInsertResult) {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                    System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
                }else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                        System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    }
                }
            }
            //system.debug('Inserted::'+punchListInsertResult[0].getId());
        }
        if(punchListSharesUpdate.size()>0 && punchListSharesUpdate != null){
            Database.SaveResult[] punchListUpdateResult = Database.update(punchListSharesUpdate,false);
            system.debug('Updated::'+punchListUpdateResult[0].getId());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom sharing rows have to provide more access than the Organization-Wide Default. In this case, the default for your external users is irrelevant, because you're inserting at least some shares to internal users - the owners of all of the Contacts on the Account. `con.OwnerId` does not give you the Id of their Community User.

Note from [Using Apex Managed Sharing to Create Custom Record Sharing Logic](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic), under Sharing Table -> Access Level,

> This field must be set to an access level that is higher than the organization’s default access level for the parent object. For more information, see Access Levels.

As a side note, this

```
if(MapIdAccLstConts.get(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c).size()>0 && MapIdAccLstConts.get(plRecInst.grnk_Account__c) != null){
```

is backwards. Your null guard won't short-circuit the `NullPointerException` if it comes second.